# How to use a conditional statement in a post loop but not count towards the "posts_per_page" if false

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP_Query which has the "posts_per_page" parameter set to 12. I am then using a while loop to iterate over all of the posts and an IF statement to check whether a condition is true or false. I would like to be able to display 12 posts which return true however, the loop is obviously also counting each post returning false and displaying nothing. For example, 5 posts would be displayed but the other 7 are not displayed.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'         => $post_slug,
   'posts_per_page'    => 12,
   'paged'             => 1,
   'post_status'       => 'publish',
);

 $topicsHub = new WP_Query($args);

 <?php while ( $topicsHub->have_posts() ) : $topicsHub->the_post();
           
   $resource_type = get_post_type();

   if($resource_type == 'tools') {
      $stream = get_field('stream_name', get_the_ID());
                    
      $tooltype = get_field('tools_type', get_the_ID());
      $stream_name = $stream;
      foreach ($options['streams'] as $key => $subscription) {
        if(in_array($subscription['parent_stream_name'], $stream)){
          $stream_name = [];
          $stream_name[] = $subscription['name'];
            break;
        }
      }
      // Custom function             
      if(check_if_user_has_access($stream_name, 'something')) {
        if($tooltype == 'free') {
          continue;
        }  
      } else {
         if($tooltype == 'premium') {
            continue;
         }
      }
   }
   ?>
   <div class="u-12 u-6@sm u-4@md resource__main-tab--item">

      <?php get_template_part('partial/content', 'topics-card'); ?>

   </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I understand why this is happening but am not sure how I could only show 12 posts that only return true.

Comment: Two basic options: You move the check of the condition into the query as well (if at all possible), or you handle everything in PHP (select _all_ records, and then let PHP decide which of these to show.)

Comment: "Hybrid" approaches are also possible. You could read 12 records, and then when you realize you have not output a full 12 records yet, make another query for the next 12 (and then again, if those still aren't enough, etc.) You might have to set offset/page numbers for the generation of the pagination links to the correct values yourself then.